# How to print text excerpt of columns with AWK?

Tags: regex, bash, csv, replace, awk

I'm facing a challenge to print formated values of a csv file in the format showed bellow:

```
id=Z123456;pseudocode=zxcdsa-12345
id=2345678;pseudocode=123456-rewqa
id=abcsd34;pseudocode=23456
```

I'm trying to get this desirable output:

```
Z123456;zxcdsa-12345
2345678;123456-rewqa
abcsd34;23456
```

With the command bellow I can print both columns but I don't know how to extract the text piece from both columns $1 and $2

```
awk -F";" '{ print $1 ";" $2}' sample.csv
```

With $1 is needed to extract the portion between id= and the semi-colon field delimiter. For the second column $2 the match pattern to print is after the string "pseudocode=" until the end of the line.

After I would end up write the result in a file like:

```
awk -F";" '{ print $1 ";" $2}' sample.csv > result.csv
```

How can I accomplish this result with awk?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `;` and `=` as field separators:

```
awk -F'[;=]' '{ print $2 ";" $4 }' file
```

Where `[;=]` is a character class for `;` and `=`

or with sed:

```
sed 's/[^=;]*=//g' file
```

Comment: There's nothing GNU-awk-specific about that, it's POSIX syntax.

Comment: For solaris is necessary to use this command nawk -F'[;=]' '{ print $2 "\t" $4 }'  file